# The transaction aborted

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

im creating a C# and WCF service which picks up msgs from MSMQ.

This is using transactional MSMQ. within the business logic, there is a condition and that condition then places a new message on a different transactional queue however I seem to always get an exception thrown and not sure where to go from here

"System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted.\r\n at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedAborted.CreateAbortingClone(InternalTransaction tx)\r\n at System.Transactions.DependentTransaction..ctor(IsolationLevel isoLevel, InternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean blocking)\r\n at System.Transactions.Transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption cloneOption)\r\n at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.SetCurrent(Transaction newCurrent)\r\n at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.PushScope()\r\n at System.Transactions.TransactionScope..ctor(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption)\r\n at TMC.Services.Implementation.InboundMessageHandler.Msmq.MsmqDispatcher.Dispatch(String queueFormatAndLocation, Object itemToPlaceOnQueue, Boolean traceMessage) in E:\Msmq\MsmqDispatcher.cs:line 39\r\n at TMC.Services.Implementation.InboundMessageHandler.OmhDispatcher.AckNackDispatcher.SendAckTo

Tg(SendAckToTgRequest request) in E:\AckNackDispatcher.cs:line 38"

Any ideas at all?

the code for when it is placing it on the queue:

```
var queue = new MessageQueue(queueFormatAndLocation);
            var msg = new System.Messaging.Message {Body = itemToPlaceOnQueue, Priority = MessagePriority.High, UseDeadLetterQueue = true, UseTracing = traceMessage};
            using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
            {
                queue.Send(msg, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic); // send the message
                ts.Complete(); // complete the transaction
            }
```

in terms of the queueFormatAndLocation, it is correct:

"FormatName:Direct=OS:.\private$\AckMsgs"

Answer (score 1):

This helps and seems to work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22SYSTEM.MESSAGING.MESSAGEQUEUETRANSACTION.%23CTOR%22);k(SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22SYSTEM.MESSAGING.MESSAGEQUEUE.%23CTOR%22);k(SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

basically using the MessageQueueTransasction and MessageQueue class. the reason for the MQT is to use it within an existing transaction (in my scenario). this seems to work.

code:

```
 using (var mqt = new MessageQueueTransaction())
            {
                mqt.Begin();
                MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(queueFormatAndLocation);
                mq.Send(itemToPlaceOnQueue, mqt);
                mqt.Commit();
            }
```